# Displaying products in index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display products in my ProductsController using the following action:

```
def index
  @products = Products.find(params[:id])
end
```

And my index.html.erb:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <p>
        <b>Product:</b>
        <%= product.name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Products without an ID)
```

I'm kind of new to rails so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be more careful with the language you are using to describe what you're trying to do. Being loose and sloppy with it has an impact both on how other people understand you as well as how you think about what you're doing.

That said, you're using an `index` action, which is used to list or provide an *index* of records, but then you're trying to get a single product (`find(id)`). These things are incongruent. Even your variable name is incongruent with the data you're loading.

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end

def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the future, you should read a little more closely and read the error messages you're getting (this one straight up tells you that params doesn't have an id for this action, cluing you into what's going on).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for all the misunderstandings. However how can I do if I want to identify the products being shown in my index view? What I want to say is, let's say I have the following div "<div class="section " id="section0"><h1>Product 1</h1></div>". How can I identify that this product has the id=1 so that when I click it, all the attributes that belongs to it will be shown correctly in the show action.

Comment: You're getting your terms all mixed up. The methods in your controllers, referred to as “actions” in the domain model, are responsible for retrieving the information needed for the view to render. Your mental model of how these parts work together is pretty twisted up, and it'd be pretty hard for me to help on StackOverflow. I recommend reading over the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) again to try to get yourself sorted out.